# What is a good name from mythology for a group of humans who cannot feel pain or emotion?

Tags: humans, alternate-worlds, names

I've got a situation where I need a name for a group of humans who cannot feel any pain or emotion (Kinda like CIPA, but without emotion as well). These have been stripped off them by a supernatural creature (that I've named Lamia, after the Greek myth, who in my world is the first Succubus - I know that many consider Lilith as the first but I want to stay away from that path)

Basically these humans then follow Lamia and guard her. They do not sleep, they do not feel, they keep going until their heart stops. They push their bodies beyond their limits (so super strength, speed, etc.) I'm stumped with coming up with a name for these people and don't want to use anything contemporary. I'd prefer something out of myth but I  haven't been able to find anything similar (Most monsters and beast are exactly the opposite - reflecting the base emotions of humans)

I'm not asking what they would do or what they would be like (I already know) I'm just stumped in what to call them. They only appear in one story and are basically cannon fodder.

If anyone knows of any creature from any mythological pantheon that fits the bill, that'll be a great help!

Thanks!

Skattered

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, Skattered. It looks like what you're creating has a lot in common with Zombies, except for pushing their bodies beyond their capabilities which of course introduces higher rates of failure as bones break and tendons tear, etc. Is that what you were going for?

Comment: Have you tried throwing some words into google translate and see if anything useful comes out in e.g. Latin? I got the *Sensu Carent*, how about that. It translates to "they are devoid". Or the *Dolere* translating to "absence of pain". Why not make up your own myth fitting these creatures :)

Comment: Hi guys. These humans aren't really zombies as they still have rational thought and motivations (e.g. one actually killed herself because she was already a self harmer and had the ability to feel stripped off her. She cut herself to the point of severing tendons because her body didn't tell her to stop) It's more the idea that these people are able to be the perfect guards, going well beyond the limit that an ordinary fighter type character will go through. (Think the Black Knight in MP's Holy Grail... just without the quips) Didn't think about the google translate. Good Idea.

Answer (score 1):

**Heartless ones**.

There are a lot of myths where (usually a villain) arranges for his heart to be kept safe at some location outside of his body, and because of this cannot be killed.  [The Giant Who Had No Heart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Giant_Who_Had_No_Heart_in_His_Body) is an example, and Koshchey the Deathless from Russian mythology is similar - his heart or soul or what have you is stored away.  Voldemort from Harry Potter of course pulls a very similar trick with his Horcrux maneuver.

One usually does not read that persons who are missing their hearts have no emotions.  Except for the Tin Man.

> "I thought I had beaten the Wicked Witch then, and I worked harder
>   than ever; but I little knew how cruel my enemy could be. She thought
>   of a new way to kill my love for the beautiful Munchkin maiden, and
>   made my axe slip again, so that it cut right through my body,
>   splitting me into two halves. Once more the tinsmith came to my help
>   and made me a body of tin, fastening my tin arms and legs and head to
>   it, by means of joints, so that I could move around as well as ever.
>   But, alas! I had now no heart, so that I lost all my love for the
>   Munchkin girl, and did not care whether I married her or not. I
>   suppose she is still living with the old woman, waiting for me to come
>   after her.
>   https://www.gutenberg.org/files/55/55-h/55-h.htm

I find that sequence so poignant.  In any case your Heartless have had their hearts removed by Lamia (which seems a very Greek mythology sort of thing to do!) and possibly replaced with something else.  The process leaves them with no emotion, no pain, and deathless.

Comment: Thanks for that, except they are still human, can still die, they just don't feel pain nor feel one way or the other about dying. Heartless also has been popularised by Kingdom Hearts and I'd rather stay away from things that are already IP'd (Especially where Disney is involved... sooooo would not like to be on the bad end of that sort of law suit!)

Answer (score 0):

**Bronze Men** - I'm not saying that they are literally made of bronze but bronze was a very strong metal for the ancient Greeks.  Nor do they have to all be men (though in those days it would be likely).  This leads to mythical interpretation where people will take the metaphorical name and spread tales of people actually made of bronze.

Or, more PC to modern readers:  **The Bronze** (but that sounds like pandering to the professionally offended to me).

Other options:

**Goloms**

**Titans**

**Myrmidons**

Comment: Myrmidons sounds good and on the right lines. Even archaic sounding enough that it would fit into the world. Thanks for that one.

Comment: Of all of them, Myrmidons were a real group of people:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myrmidons

Comment: Even better! Thanks!